# Javascript Пробуксовка скроллинга на определенных элементах

Tags: javascript, ui

Каким образом можно реализовать пробуксовку нативного скроллинга страницы при достижении верхних границ определенных элементов, как это сделано например тут http://www.rbc.ru/economics/22/09/2017/59c4906b9a7947ecd19362c3?from=main при прокручивании на следующую/предыдущую статью.

Comment: Судя по их коду это похоже на самописный слайдер, только вместо картинки там почти целая страница. И один слайд (страница) наезжает на другой. Изменить поведение скроллинга можно удалив действия по умолчанию для этого события, например `window.onscroll = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}` Но нужен не только скролл, еще  `window.ontouchmove`, `document.onkeydown`. А потом реализовать свое поведение при скролле в слайдере.